# Pig round down to the nth decimal place

Tags: apache-pig, rounding

How do you round a float or double down to the nth decimal place in pig. For example

```
f(3.999999, 1) =  3.9
f(3.42317, 2) = 3.42
f(1.03, 1) = 1.0
```

I really only need to round to the 1st decimal place but thought i'd leave the question general. I saw the "pig round decimal to two places" question but the answer wasn't explained to the point where i could adapt it to this. Thanks

---

### Answer

Turns out math solves this pretty easily. Just do:

```
FLOOR(column * 10^n) / 10^n
```

Comment: fyi. "The too-often seen trick of doing (1000.0 * ROUND(x/1000)) is not only hard to read but also fails to produce numerically accurate results"
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ROUND_TO.html

Answer (score 5):

PIG has [ROUND_TO](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ROUND_TO.html). That will do the rounding based on the decimal points needed.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ROUND_TO(input,num_of_decimal_places);
```

Example:

Input file:

```
3.999999
3.42317
1.03
```

A = LOAD 'file' as (num:float);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ROUND_TO(num,2);
dump B;

Output:

```
(4.0)
(3.42)
(1.03)
```